# How to make popup slide down from under the header in Jquery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Right now when i summon a popup it appears over the header and then slides down beneath it. Check out what it looks like now.

[image]

I would like the popup to slide down from underneath the header. I've tried setting the z index of the popup lower than the header but it didnt do anything. Apparently you need to explicitly set the positioning of elements to use z index but when I did that it totally messed up the UI.

Here's the relevant code

HTML:

```
 <div data-role="popup" id="alertPopup" class="ui-content" data-shadow="false" data-transition="slidedown" data-dismissible="false" data-corners="false" data-position-to="origin">
   <p id="popupText"></p>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
var horizontal = Math.floor(window.innerWidth/2);
var vertical = 80;

var popupOptions = {
    x: horizontal,
    y: vertical
};

if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
              $("#popupText").text("No transit options could be found.");//using popups instead of alerts because these will go away by themselves instead of forcing user to tap.
              $("#alertPopup").popup("open",popupOptions);
                  setTimeout(function() {
                   $("#alertPopup").popup("close");
                }, 3000);
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/gvsqenvf/

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle or a code snippet.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/gvsqenvf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using a jQM popup widget will not work for this because jQM creates a transparent overlay that covers the page, then a popup container above the overlay and then it places the popup within the container. So there is no way to have the popup be under the header.

Instead, you could use an absolutely positioned DIV for your popup and use the jQuery slideToggle() method to display it.

Add the notification div to the content:

```
<div data-role="content" id="content">
    <div id="notify" class="ui-body-inherit ui-content">
        <p id="notifyText">hello</p>
    </div> 

    I am Content
</div>
```

Setup the CSS to absolutely position the div and hide it until needed:

```
#notify {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
#notify p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

In the script, set the text, calculate position and show it with slide toggle (I added a timeout on the show just so the fiddle can finish drawing the page before the notification is shown).

```
$("#notifyText").text("No transit options could be found.");
var $notify = $("#notify");
var vertical = $(".ui-header").outerHeight() -1; //height of header
var w = $notify.width();
var left = (Math.floor((window.innerWidth - w) / 2));
$notify.css({ left: w + "px", top: vertical + "px"});
setTimeout(function() {
    $notify.slideToggle(500); //delay showing for the fiddle
}, 500);

setTimeout(function() {
    $notify.slideToggle(500);
}, 5000);
```

> Your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/gvsqenvf/2/)**